# Combining AJAX/JSON call with iScroll

Tags: json, jquery-mobile, iscroll

I am making a list form my JQM site from JSON data and are having no trouble with this. Now I want to add iScroll to the scene and if I use static list it works just fine, but when I get the list from JSON it won't fetch how many li I have and I can not scroll down to the bottom if I have lets say 20 li. I dont know how to combine my javascript so here is what i got so far [EDIT]:

```
var myScroll;   

$(document).on('pageshow', function (){
    var userid=1,
        dataUrl = 'http://duefmun.dk/html5data/playermenu.php?callback=?&userid=' + userid,
        dataCallback = function (data) {
            var content = [];
            $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                content.push(val.list);
            });
            $('#games').html(content.join('')).listview('refresh');
        },
        fetchData = function () {
            myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
            if (myScroll.isReady()){
                $.getJSON(dataUrl, dataCallback);
            }
        };
    fetchData();
    setInterval(fetchData, 20000);

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(loaded, 200);  }, false);

});
```

Hope this makes sense and any help is appreciated :-)

EDIT: I have edited the post with something I think should be right but it is still not working? Please help :-/

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you should create iScroll after you get your data. So, your code should be:

```
...
fetchData = function () {           
        if (myScroll.isReady()){
            $.getJSON(dataUrl, dataCallback);
        }
    };
fetchData();
setInterval(fetchData, 20000);
myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
...
```